# OnClick event with HTML table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to open a new aspx page when i click on a particular cell in my HTML table.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_td.asp please visit this url it may helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

Get the element by the tag name  and assign a click event to it. A simple anonymous function will do.

Javascript:

```
var tablecell = document.getElementsByTagName("TD"):

for( index = 0; index < tablecell.length ; index++)
{
  tablecell[i].onclick = function(){
  window.open( 'newpage.aspx');
  };
}
```

This will add click event to all td elements, through out the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
Add this to your table cell onclick="redirectpage()"

```
function redirectpage()
{
window.location="www.google.com";//page location
}
```

Solution 2:
Better would be if you use a hyperlink inside the table cell. Its a more elegant solution.

Solution 3: Add this to your javascript

```
window.onload=setclickevent;
function setclickevent()
{
var myTab=document.getElementById('table');//Replace with your table id.
myTab.rows[0/*Row*/].cells[0/*Row's cell*/].onclick=function(){alert('event added');};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table cell would have something like

<td> Test cell </td> you can change it to have hyperlink as

<td onclick='window.location="www.google.com"'> Test cell </td>

if you want to open in new window then use window.open('www.google.com').

Hope this helps you.

Happy Coding!!!